# htaccess - rewrite url with two rules

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

Okay, I am having a little trouble with .htaccess as I am a beginner with it. This is what I am trying to accomplish.

**URL DESIRED:** example.com/package/forest/

What I have now:

```
RewriteRule ^package/forest/$
/deep/file/do_stuff.php?action=package&location=forest [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This is working as intended, when you go to example.com/package/forest you get the page that is produced by do_stuff.php. The hard part that I can't get, is what if I want to send extra GET variables to the do_stuff page but keep the same URL.

**STARTING URL:** example.com/package/forest/list/5/2015-10-03

**STILL DESIRED URL:** example.com/package/forest

The difference being, I want the rewrite or redirect, not sure the term, to be

```
/deep/file/do_stuff.php?action=package&location=forest&pictures=5&date=2015-10-03
```

this time.

Not sure how to stack the rules so that I end up with the same URL whether they pass extra variables or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^package/forest/list/(\d)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$ package/forest/deep/file/do_stuff.php?action=package&location=forest&pictures=$1&date=$2
```

The regex captures two groups, one with a single digit and one with the date. These are used later as $1 and $2.

Unfortunately I cannot test it as I am using nginx, so I am not 100% sure if I'm right.
I thought about whether the uri was going to get rewritten again after the first rewrite because "package/forest/" would still match, but the dollar sign at the end of the string should prevent any uri longer than that from matching. 
For the same reason you don't have to worry about stacking; the first rule will only apply to short uri's ending with "forest/", the second only to those with a date in the end.
On the other hand I am wondering, why you are using the QSA flag. A uri containing a query will never match because of the trailing dollar sign.